# VMWare: always show host cursor

Tags: vmware, mouse, cursor

Is there a way to force vmware to show host mouse pointer? I mean that I want to see always 2 pointers host and guest.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an very old question, it was never marked as duplicate, so I suppose it's still relevant and I will attempt to answer it:

Here's how this can be done using VMware Workstation (Pro) 14+
According to official [WMware docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-53BB2D29-9ADA-4028-B8F0-FD6905F37762.html):

Cursor settings control cursor behavior for the virtual machines that you run in Workstation Pro.
To configure cursor settings, select `Edit > Preferences > Input`.

| Setting | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Automatically grab and ungrab the mouse | Virtual machines release the cursor when you point outside of the virtual machine window. When this setting is selected, you can use the host system without first pressing a key combination. VMware Tools must be installed in the virtual machine to use this feature. |
| Hide cursor on ungrab | The cursor does not appear in the virtual machine display after input is transferred back to the host system. If you have multiple virtual machines open at the same time, selecting this setting helps you track the active cursor. VMware Tools must be installed in the virtual machine to use this feature. |
| Optimize mouse for games | Select mouse behavior for computer games. In some computer games, you move the pointer to the edge of the screen to pan the scene or scroll. By optimizing the virtual mouse for games, you can achieve this effect in a virtual machine. **Automatic** Workstation Pro determines when to optimize mouse motion. This is the default setting. **Always** Mouse motion is always optimized for games. **Never** Mouse motion is never optimized. When you play computer games in a virtual machine, the optimized mouse is usually not released from the virtual machine. Some applications, such as AutoCAD, are incorrectly identified as games. Select this setting if you use AutoCAD and find that the mouse cannot pass freely from the virtual machine to the host system or if pointer speed is different when you use AutoCAD. |

My note about the "Optimize mouse for games" option:

Besides others, it changes what exactly happens when clicked inside the guest VM window to start mouse grab.

Option **Always** causes that when clicked inside guest VM window, the guest's mouse/pointer remains on the position it was previously left at, when ungrabbing controls. You begin movement of guest's mouse/pointer from that last position. (Automatic grab/ungrab will not work)

Option **Never** causes that when clicked inside guest VM window, the guest's mouse/pointer will instantly move to the position of host's cursor/pointer.
You begin movement of guest's mouse/pointer from host's mouse/pointer position.